# Dash not searching files

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, encryption, ecryptfs

Unity's Dash is not searching files that I have opened before, only Applications. Neither Global nor Files lenses are showing any results.

In then Files lens, I can view most recent documents, but that's it.

I suspect it is caused by my home folder's encryption, due to errors displayed in /var/log/syslog:

> [ 1868.382095] ecryptfs_encrypt_page: Error attempting to write lower page; rc = [-5]
>   [ 1868.382099] ecryptfs_writepage: Error encrypting page (upper index [0x000000000000000f])

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The error messages you're seeing here are related to ecryptfs obviously, but they're actually a [red herring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  That is, they should not actually be causing Unity's Dash to not search your files.

I thought, perhaps, Unity blacklisted encrypted files in the way that [updatedb](http://manpg.es/updatedb) and [locate](http://manpg.es/locate) do, but that does not appear to be the case.  I can confirm that I have an encrypted directory with file names, and Unity's dash is able to search my files okay.

*Full disclosure: I am the author of Ubuntu's Encrypted Home Directory feature and the current maintainer of eCryptfs.*